# Why the health checks cannot reach the target groups in an AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

This is the targets in my target group. They corresponds to the docker processes running in my ecs service.

[image]

As you can see all processes are marked as either `draining` or `unhealthy`.

Here is how I define my `Health checks`,

[image]

I have tried the health check url on a local docker process and the url works as expected.

[image]

The same log messages are not found incloud watch log. I presume the healthcheck url is not called at all.

Here is my container definition in my task

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot, I have mapped port 0 to 8090. I believe it is how to enable dynamic mapping.

Also I have set the network mode to 'Bridge'

How can get the health check to work? I think currently it is the reason why I cannot reach the underlying docker processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the default security group when I created the ecs cluster

The default SG is

[image]

So basically no traffic can reach the ec2 instance that hosts the docker process.

I added a very permissive  security group and it is working and I can reach the healthcheck url

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was problem with health check. I added Success codes 200 but my services are secured and it returns 401 on health check.

I added 200,401,404 as health check success codes.